# Why does my Javascript code validate, but returns no results?

Tags: javascript, forms

I'm puzzled as to why the result of the Javascript computation does not appear in the input field of id "Between." I ran the JS through jshint.com and it found no errors. This will be used in an iPhone environment on an html page. I'm very new to JS. I picked up some simple math code elsewhere and massaged it into the shape you see here. Can you JS coders show me where my script has gone wrong?

> ```
> function heatpit(form) {
>     var e = form.elements.LENGTH.value, // put LENGTH (number of minutes) field value into variable e
>         f = form.elements.STOPS.value, // put STOPS field value into variable f
>         secs2 = e * 60, // convert the minutes into seconds
>         periods = f + '1', // add 1 to the pit stop number get the total  number of divisions throughout the LENGTH
>         result2 = secs2 / periods, // divide the LENGTH by the number of periods
>         seconds = result2 % 60, // use modulus operator to get the remainder and convert it into seconds figure
>         minutes = Math.floor(result2 / 60), // get the minute figure as a digit
>         time = minutes + ":" + seconds; // concatenate everything into minutes and seconds
>
>     form.elements.between.value = time; // display "time" value in the "between" field
> }
>
> var resultPitStops = document.getElementById('resultPitStops');
> resultPitStops.onclick = function () {
>     var form = document.getElementById('form2');
>     heatpit(form);
> };
> ```

Comment: Can you post the HTML of the form?

Answer (score 0):

For one, you've got commas as the end of each statement. they should be semicolons:

```
var e = form.elements.LENGTH.value;
                                 ^---semicolon
var f = form.elements.STOPS.value;
etc...
```

Then:

```
periods = f + '1'
```

`f` is retrieved from a form field, and Javascript treats those values as strings, so what you're doing is taking a string, and concatenating with with another string. If the stops value is `123`, then you get `1231`, not `124`.

You then take that string value of `1231` and use it as a divisor. Most likely javascript is casting it to '0', so you're producing a divide-by-zero error.

So... check your browser's javascript error console. In Firefox, just hit shift-ctrl-J to pop it up. And watch for errors as the function executes.

Comment: The commas actually work if you're defining several `var`s in one statement. `var a, b, c` is just as valid as `var a;var b;var c;`. The rest of this answer seems correct, though; good job.

Comment: true enough, but if you're separating onto multiple lines anyways, and doing all kinds of initialization, you should do it as seperate lines - if only for readability.

Comment: Also, `'1231'` is evaluated as `1231` when it's in a mathematical context.

Comment: The heatpit(form) now returns the correct answer when I make it: "f = parseInt(form.elements.STOPS.value)," However, I'm still struggling with the concatenation issue with the first function. ParseInt doesn't seem to work there. Applying parseInt to b and c to add them together doesn't produce valid math results.

Comment: To do numerical addition just do `f + 1`, without the quotes. As long as F is a number, that'll do addition, not concatenation. For some basic debugging, you can do `alert(typeof(f))` to see what it is before doing the addition.

Comment: OK, I changed the '1' to get 1. I also added the parseInt to b = and c = , and the coding is working better, but the result is not perfect. If you enter a = 100 (for 100cc tank of fuel), b = 9 (minutes of driving time), c = 60 (seconds of driving time; equals 10 minutes when added to the minutes figure), and d = 90 (for 90cc of fuel left), then you are saying you drove 10 minutes and used 10cc of fuel. This means 1cc of fuel per minute. So the result should be 1:00, but what is shown is :54 (54 seconds), which is just under 1.00. This needs to be more accurate than that, if possible.